# Generic function that accepts a SQLx PgPool or MySqlPool

Tags: rust, rust-sqlx

I'd like to setup a generic function that accepts a SQLx [PgPool](https://docs.rs/sqlx/latest/sqlx/type.PgPool.html) or [MySqlPool](https://docs.rs/sqlx/latest/sqlx/type.MySqlPool.html).

```rust
use dotenv::dotenv;
use sqlx::postgres::PgPool;
use sqlx::{Pool, Database};
use std::env;

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Todo {
    id: i64,
    description: String,
    done: bool,
}

#[actix_web::main]
async fn main() -> anyhow::Result<()> {
    dotenv().ok();
    let pool = PgPool::connect(&env::var("DATABASE_URL")?).await?;
    list_todos(&pool).await?;
    Ok(())
}



async fn list_todos<D: Database>(pool: &Pool<D>) -> anyhow::Result<Vec<Todo>> {
    let todos = sqlx::query_as!(
        Todo,
        r#"
        SELECT id, description, done
        FROM todos
        ORDER BY id
        "#
    )
    .fetch_all(pool)
    .await?;

    Ok(todos)
}
```

The error I see is:

```rust
32 |     .fetch_all(pool)
   |      ^^^^^^^^^ expected type parameter `D`, found struct `Postgres`
   |
   = note: expected type parameter `D`
                      found struct `Postgres`

error[E0277]: the trait bound `for<'c> &'c mut <D as sqlx::Database>::Connection: Executor<'c>` is not satisfied
```

Any hints on how to setup the function to accept a PgPool or MySqlPool param? Thanks

Comment: Being there a few months ago...made a script with python :/

Answer (score 3):

The [query macro docs](https://docs.rs/sqlx/latest/sqlx/macro.query.html) state that:

> The QueryAs instance will be bound to the same database type as query!() was compiled against (e.g. you cannot build against a Postgres database and then run the query against a MySQL database).

However, [the function](https://docs.rs/sqlx/latest/sqlx/fn.query.html) does not have this limitation. Knowing this we can build some functions that are generic over any executor type of any database type.

---

When you're trying to be generic over any backend in sqlx you need to be generic over the **database** (sqlite, mysql, postgresql, etc), the **executor** (`PgPool`, `SqlitePool`, a raw `Connection`, a `Transaction`, etc), any **encoded** (parameters/bind variables), and **decoded** (query_as return types) values.

For example, creating a table:

```
pub async fn create_products_table<'a, DB, E>(e: E) -> Result<(), Error>
where
    DB: Database,
    <DB as HasArguments<'a>>::Arguments: IntoArguments<'a, DB>,
    E: Executor<'a, Database = DB>,
{
    sqlx::query(include_str!(
        "../sql/create_products_table.sql"
    ))
    .execute(e)
    .await?;
    Ok(())
}
```

Selecting items from a table:

```
pub struct Product {
    name: String,
    other: String,
}

impl<'r, R> FromRow<'r, R> for Product
where
    R: Row,
    //Here we have bounds for index by str
    for<'c> &'c str: ColumnIndex<R>,
    //We need this bound because `Product` contains `String`
    for<'c> String: Decode<'c, R::Database> + Type<R::Database>,
{
    fn from_row(row: &'r R) -> Result<Self, Error> {
        //Here we index by str
        let name = row.try_get("name")?;
        //Here we index by str
        let other = row.try_get("other")?;
        Ok(Self { name, other })
    }
}

pub async fn select_products<'a, 'b, DB, E>(
    e: E,
    name: &'a str,
) -> impl Stream<Item = Result<Product, Error>> + 'b
where
    'a: 'b,
    DB: Database,
    <DB as HasArguments<'a>>::Arguments: IntoArguments<'a, DB>,
    for<'c> E: 'a + Executor<'c, Database = DB>,

    //We need this bound because `Product` contains `String`
    for<'c> String: Decode<'c, DB> + Type<DB>,

    //We need this bound because 'name' function argument is of type `&str`
    for<'c> &'c str: Encode<'c, DB> + Type<DB>,

    //We need this bound for `FromRow` implementation or if we intend on indexing rows by str.
    //You will probably need to write your own `FromRow` implementation.
    for<'c> &'c str: ColumnIndex<<DB as Database>::Row>,
{
    query_as(include_str!("../sql/select_products.sql"))
        .bind(name)
        .fetch(e)
}
```

I would *love* for this to be more streamlined or documented as it seems ripe for macros. Perhaps I will draft some docs for a PR to sqlx. Let me know if you need more examples.

---

I am also aware of the [Any](https://docs.rs/sqlx/latest/sqlx/struct.Any.html) database driver, however it has the distinct disadvantage of requiring an opaque type with no trivial way of converting from concrete to opaque types. This means you have to use `AnyPool` everywhere you'd be generic over a database and can never use a concrete `PgPool` or `SqlitePool`. You also must solely rely on connection strings to differentiate database implementations (yuck)

Comment: This answer removes the actual cause of the error: The code gen inside the `query_as!` macro

Comment: @sebpuetz, You have already explained that the functions aren't specialized at compile time like the macros, though; so I just wanted to add the generic bounds for the OP and googlers

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the proc macro expansion for the `query!` macro, it looks like they fill in the specific type for the underlying DB based on the connection string in the `.env` file. Thus, the macro is generating specialized code *inside the function* for the `Postgres` implementation but your function is generic over different `Database` implementors, i.e. expecting `Pool<Db> where Db: Database`.

cargo expand output with some reformatting:

```rust
    use ::sqlx::Arguments as _;
    let query_args =
        <sqlx::postgres::Postgres as ::sqlx::database::HasArguments>::Arguments::default();
    let todos = ::sqlx::query_with::<sqlx::postgres::Postgres, _>(
        "\n        SELECT id, description, done\n        FROM todos\n        ORDER BY id\n        ",
        query_args,
    )
    .try_map(|row: sqlx::postgres::PgRow| {
        use ::sqlx::Row as _;
        let sqlx_query_as_id = row.try_get_unchecked::<i32, _>(0usize)?;
        let sqlx_query_as_description = row.try_get_unchecked::<String, _>(1usize)?;
        let sqlx_query_as_done = row.try_get_unchecked::<bool, _>(2usize)?;
        Ok(Todo {
            id: sqlx_query_as_id,
            description: sqlx_query_as_description,
            done: sqlx_query_as_done,
        })
    })
    .fetch_all(pool)
    .await?;
    Ok(todos)
```

Even if you follow @Netwave's suggestion to use a generic `Executor`, the macro will still produce the same non-generic code inside the function and refuse to compile. Although, there is the difference that @Netwave's answer uses the `query` function instead of the compile-time checked `query!` macro.

Using the `Executor` trait for dispatching the queries and dropping support for compile time checks allows to write something like the following:

```rust
async fn list_todos_unchecked<'e, Exe>(pool: Exe) -> anyhow::Result<()>
where
    Exe: Executor<'e>,
    <Exe::Database as HasArguments<'e>>::Arguments:
        IntoArguments<'e, <Exe as Executor<'e>>::Database>,
{
    let todos = sqlx::query(
        "\n        SELECT id, description, done\n        FROM todos\n        ORDER BY id\n        ",
    )
    .fetch_all(pool)
    .await?;
    Ok(())
}
```

`sqlx` also has support for the `Any` driver that supports proxying to any enabled DB driver at runtime. `sqlx` doesn't support macros based on the `Any` driver yet but it's tracked in [this issue](https://github.com/launchbadge/sqlx/issues/964).

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't test it properly, but you could leverage `Executor` directly  as generics.
From the [documentation](https://docs.rs/sqlx/latest/sqlx/trait.Executor.html):

> A type that contains or can provide a database connection to use for
> executing queries against the database.
>
> No guarantees are provided that successive queries run on the same
> physical database connection.
>
> A Connection is an Executor that guarantees that successive queries
> are ran on the same physical database connection.
>
> **Implemented for the following:**
>
> **&Pool &mut PoolConnection &mut Connection**

```rust
async fn list_todos<'e, Exe: Executor<'e>>(executor: Exe) -> anyhow::Result<()>
where
    <Exe::Database as HasArguments<'e>>::Arguments:
        IntoArguments<'e, <Exe as Executor<'e>>::Database>,
{
    let todos = sqlx::query(
        r#"
        SELECT id, description, done
        FROM todos
        ORDER BY id
        "#,
    )
    .execute(executor)
    .await?;

    Ok(())
}
```

> Disclaimer: return types and other things changed a bit since I don't
> have an environment for testing it properly. But it compiles without
> problems for the Executor bindings. You would have to adapt whats
> left.