# Rust sqlx generic function over specific backends

Tags: rust, rust-sqlx

I am trying to abstract a query over 2 backends (postgres and sqlite). I understand why the following does not work

```
async fn my_query<T>(p: sqlx::Pool<T>, bar: &Uuid) -> Result<(), Error>
where
    T: sqlx::Database,
{
    sqlx::query_as::<_, (i64,)>("select id from foo where bar = ?")
        .bind(bar)
        .fetch_one(&p)
        .await?;
}
```

However, I would like to say something like:

```
where
    T: sqlx::Sqlite AND sqlx::Postgres
```

In other words, can I express that I will obey the most restrictive implementation? Obviously `Sqlite` and `Postgres` are not traits, but the concept I want to phrase in Rust is that the restriction should apply to the most restrictive thing, whatever that may be.

I was able to find something which recommended I define a db, executor,d(encoded) value bounds, but then I also have to include the bounds for every type I want to use in the function body:

[Generic function that accepts a SQLx PgPool or MySqlPool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70560174/generic-function-that-accepts-a-sqlx-pgpool-or-mysqlpool)

I'm hoping rust has some nice way of expressing this, but I may be out of luck, and have to dive into a fairly messy looking implementation.